# useSelector hook returns 'undefined' from initial state

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm playing around with React/Redux/TypeScript stack and trying to figure out how it works and should work.

I have a simple test application and when I'm trying to get data from the initial state - I receive all values as 'undefined' (no matter what I try to get from the initial state).

See code below:

Component:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { CurrencyExchangeState } from '../store/exchange/types';

export const Exchange = () => {

    // tried this before - same result
    // const currentCurrency = useSelector<CurrencyExchangeState,
    //     CurrencyExchangeState["currentCurrency"]>
    //     (state => state.currentCurrency);

    const selectCurrentCurrency = (state: CurrencyExchangeState) => state.currentCurrency
    const currentCurrency = useSelector(selectCurrentCurrency)
    
    console.log(currentCurrency) // undefined
    // <...>
```

Types Interface '../store/exchange/types.ts':

```
export interface CurrencyExchangeState {
    sum: number,
    mode: string,
    currentCurrency: string
}
```

Reducer '..store/exchange/reducers.ts':

```
import {
  CurrencyExchangeState,
  CurrencyExchangeActionTypes,
  // ...
} from './types'

const initialState: CurrencyExchangeState = {
  sum: 0,
  mode: BUY_MODE,
  currentCurrency: UAH_CURRENCY
}

export function currencyExchangeReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: CurrencyExchangeActionTypes
): CurrencyExchangeState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_BUY_SALE:
      return {
        ...state,
        mode: action.payload
      }
    case SWITCH_CURRENCY:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentCurrency: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Redux Store index file '../store/index.ts':

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { currencyExchangeReducer } from './exchange/reducers'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    currencyExchangeReducer: currencyExchangeReducer
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
export const exchangeStore = createStore(rootReducer)
```

Could you please point what's possible could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already wrap your currency reducer by using `combineReducers` so in order to retrieve it you have to select as following:

```js
const selectCurrentCurrency = (state: CurrencyExchangeState) => state.currencyExchangeReducer.currentCurrency)
```

Comment: Apparently, instead of `CurrencyExchangeState` I should use `RootState`, which make sense because I am combining reducers. Then it works as expected. Thank you for the help!